# KDB+ Functional Select Dynamic Columns

Tags: select, dynamic, functional-programming, kdb

How can I dynamically rename more than 1 column from a table?

For example: I want to parse out 3 date columns and rename them as balanceT1, balanceT2, and balanceT3

First I parsed out the date columns:

```
balanceCols:string (cols balanceData) where ((string cols balanceData) like "*_*")and not (string cols balanceData) like "*Post*"
```

Then do a functional select to rename them, but doesn't work.

```
 balanceData:?[balanceData;();0b;(`parentPort;`portfolio;`currency;`balanceT1;`balanceT2;`balanceT3;`minBalanceTransferUsd;`odSubPort)!(`parentPort;`portfolio;`currency;balanceCol;(^;0f;`minBalanceTransferUsd);`overdraftSubPortId)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are creating a nested list of values when trying to create the dictionary, which is not the same length as the list of keys.

For example, say `balanceCol` is defined as `` `a`b`c `` then:

```
q)count(`parentPort;`portfolio;`currency;`balanceT1;`balanceT2;`balanceT3;`minBalanceTransferUsd;`odSubPort)
8
q)balanceCol:`a`b`c
q)count(`parentPort;`portfolio;`currency;balanceCol;(^;0f;`minBalanceTransferUsd);`overdraftSubPortId)
6
```

Here there are 6 values but 8 keys. To fix this you could join them elements together like so:

```
`parentPort`portfolio`currency,balanceCol,enlist[(^;0f;`minBalanceTransferUsd)],`overdraftSubPortId
```

As for making the query dynamic, the following function will allow you to build up the dictionary for the functional select based on any number of date columns whilst still keeping the column order you used above.

```
f:{[d]
  k:`parentPort`portfolio`currency,(`$"balanceT",/:string 1+til count d),`minBalanceTransferUsd`odSubPort;
  v:`parentPort`portfolio`currency,d,enlist[(^;0f;`minBalanceTransferUsd)],`overdraftSubPortId;
  :k!v;
 };
```